# Is it feasible to become a paramedic full time and do a PhD in an unrelated field?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, working-time, biology, psychology

**Do you think this is reasonable?** 
I am graduating with a BSc in neuroscience next year. I would like to be a paramedic for a little while (throughout my 20's) before switching careers and becoming a researcher in Neuroscience (for my 30's +).

Scenario A:
After completing my BSc I want to do the 2 years of training to become an EMT. A full time work schedule as an EMT would be something like 12 hour shifts, 3 days on, 3 days off, 4 nights on, 4 nights off, etc. Would it be possible to pursue a masters and a PhD in Neuroscience while working a schedule like that? I imagine that this way I would graduate towards the end of my 20's or early thirties with a PhD. Then I would like to begin a career as a researcher/lecturer. Does this sound impossibly difficult?

Scenario B:
After graduating, spend the next 2 years to become an EMT. Work as an EMT for a few years, then reduce to part-time or quit and pursue funding for a masters + PhD in my mid 20's. I hear that returning to university after a few years off might be more difficult, both to apply, and to be competitive. Is this true?

Scenario C:
Pursue my masters after I finish my BSc. Then do the 2 years to become an EMT, work as an EMT for a few years, then do a PhD. Will the relevance of the masters depreciate over time? If I already have a master's done, how long would it take to finish a PhD?

I guess in general, is this just an insane plan? Or is it possible?

Comment: Hi CECA. Which country is this? This makes a difference, as getting a scholarship for part-time studies during your Master's and PhD will be insanely difficult, and in countries with high university fees, your EMT work may be insufficient to fund your university enrollment. Also, the duration of a PhD varies with the country.

Comment: Paramedic is a real full time job. The work is pretty much unpredictable. Sometimes, you may have nothing to do during the shift so you can use the time to study. Sometimes, you may be so busy rescuing people and don't even have time to eat or go to rest room. So, yes, I think Scenario A and B are very difficult.

Comment: Thanks. Ya, should have clarified, I'm in Canada. I think it should be OK in terms of funding. I didn't know it was that difficult to find funding for graduate school... but in any case, I'm pretty confident I would be able to save enough on an EMT salary, assuming I find a job in the big city where I live & reasonably soon after completing my course.

Comment: Preparing a PhD is also a real full time job in my opinion...

Comment: As @scaahu pointed out, C is the only even theoretically possible option. It's not just a question of time: no respectable school will admit you while you work full-time "at the side." As to C, it depends on how impressive your academic credentials are. Currently, this rather new field still has large tolerance for unusual backgrounds (a leading theoretician spent almost a decade in a commune); but that is likely to change, and you need to stick out as very qualified coming from an EMT.

Comment: @gnometorule what would make me stick out as a very qualified applicant? Are you saying that good grades (in BSc), good recommendations, & a published masters thesis are somehow detracted from because of a paramedic career?

Comment: No, I mean that this is exactly what would help: if you did very well in your undergrad, have professors who might write you good recommendations (maybe talk to them about your plans so it's more likely they remember you), have a good GRE (if required), and certainly if you have research to refer to - that won't go away. You need to compare favorably in these regards, and then having followed a passion for being an EMT might not matter (some might even appreciate, although don't count on that).

Comment: @gnometorule: *No respectable school will admit you while you work full-time "at the side."*  Really?  I'm not aware of any "respectable schools" in which the student's employment is even considered as a factor in graduate admissions.

Comment: @Nate: Good luck discussing that you'll miss your coursework as it's a work day.

Comment: One comment to add: being an EMT is a tough job, you will need the days off. Sometimes, you will loose people, and you won't feel like studying or doing research. And you will be interacting with people on one of the worst days of their lives, when even the nicest person can be very difficult.

Answer (score 5):

A does sound impossibly difficult to me.  The first few years of a masters/PhD sequence are usually based on coursework.  You will need to attend classes regularly on weekdays, which seems like it would probably be incompatible with a paramedic's work schedule.  Even beyond coursework, particularly in lab sciences, you may find that parts of your research have to be done on a particular schedule.

Moreover, at all stages of graduate study, you should expect that your coursework and/or research will require a time commitment at least comparable to a full time job (40 hours per week), likely substantially more.  Many graduate students struggle with the workload, even without added commitments.  Adding a full time job, especially one with as much stress, long hours, and sleep disruption as a paramedic must have, seems to me like a burden well beyond what any human could be expected to successfully bear.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I suspected as much. How does scenario B and/or C sound? (the only difference being when I would complete my masters). After approximately 5-10 years being out of school, what challenges would there be in returning for a masters/Phd ?

Comment: @CECA: I don't really know.  Sorry.